# Does passing a function pass by reference?

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI Main(LPVOID lpParam) {
    MessageBox(0,"Hello World from DLL!\n","Hi",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return S_OK;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch(fdwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(hinstDLL);
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Main, NULL, 0, NULL);
        break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Why is that I can replace `CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Main, NULL, 0, NULL);` with `CreateThread(NULL, 0, Main, NULL, 0, NULL);` and it will still work? Is it because in C, if I pass a method, it will reduce it to a pointer to the method? Or is it because `DWORD` is a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Technically, in C, everything is passed by value, not by reference. It just looks like passing by reference when a pointer is passed as argument.
2. Most likely `DWORD` is defined as an integer that has the size of two words on the machine.
3. A function name is automatically converted to a pointer to function by the compiler.

> #### C99 §6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators
>
> A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the
>   operand of the `sizeof`operator or the unary `&`operator, a function designator with
>   type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to
>   function returning type’’.

And furthermore, you can use `*` to a pointer to function, you get the function designator as result. Using this, you can play with it a little bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);
void foo(void)
{
    printf("hello\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    func_ptr p;
    p = &foo;   //function pointer
    p();
    p = foo;    //function name is converted to function pointer
    p();
    p = *foo;   //legal
    p();
    p = *****************foo;  //still legal
    p();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello
hello
hello
hello
```